# Correcting question title and tags when problem has been completely misunderstood

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, edits, question-quality

Please consider this question for a moment:

[Why am I getting an "xxx is already defined" compiler error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687521/create-thread-using-for-loop-in-java)

I feel like it would be appropriate to edit the question so that the title and tags don't mislead.  Both of those would seem to indicate that this is a question about concurrency, but in fact this question is about a compiler error.  So, my idea is to change the question to "Why am I getting this compiler error?" and change the tags appropriately.

As I'm new to being able to edit questions, I'd just like to know if this seems reasonable to the community before I go ahead and do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**DO IT!**

Whenever you get a chance to make a title reflect the actual question, you should do so. This makes searching much more effective, and avoids unfortunate answers that respond to the title without taking the rest of the question into account...

But you should **use a more specific title** than, "Why am I getting this error?" - that doesn't tell us anything *about* the error. Perhaps, *"Why am I getting a 'variable name is already defined' error?"*

Comment: I'm convinced.  Thanks for the support.