# Should we edit/retag questions written about SO that are really about SE?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

A lot of the MSO questions that ask about Stack Overflow and/or are tagged `[stackoverflow]` really apply to Stack Exchange system-wide behaviors, and — semantically, at least — should be tagged `[stackexchange]`. Here are a few examples, which I found in five minutes just by looking through the list of `[stackoverflow]` questions in "recent" view:

- [Correcting question title and tags when problem has been completely misunderstood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64148/correcting-question-title-and-tags-when-problem-has-been-completely-misunderstood)
- [Dealing with Stalkers and Unwarranted Persecution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64128/dealing-with-stalkers-and-unwarranted-persecution)
- [How to find all the comments I posted on this site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64109/how-to-find-all-the-comments-i-posted-on-this-site)

Presumably this happens on per-site metas as well, but I'm not as familiar with those and the problem is easier to fix on MSO. Should these questions be edited to say "Stack Exchange" and/or retagged to `[stackexchange]`?

Answer (score 2):

In theory, I say yes, these should be edited and retagged, but that would flood the main page considerably.

In practice, I support a less severe approach, consistent with my usual editing philosophy: don't go hunting for such questions, but if you come across one that needs editing/retagging for another reason, go ahead and make the SO → SE change as well.

Normally I wouldn't even ask a separate question about this, but the issue is fairly common and I haven't seen much action taken on it (though I have seen some).

Comment: Agreed - only edit if you come across one in your travels, don't go looking (at least not yet anyway).

Comment: I say if you have the energy, flood the page. Page is filthy. Needs washed clean. Pops gonna edit to put it back the way it oughta be...

Answer (score 2):

This site is for Stack Exchange 2.0 support, and doubles as a per-site Meta for Stack Overflow.

Questions about the engine and core-related features should not have `[stackexchange]` on them because it's a redundant tag -- the SOFU engine and Stack Exchange 2.0 engine are now one and the same.

What I do agree with is that `[stackoverflow]` should be *untagged* from questions where it's not a specific support request or discussion about Stack Overflow specifically. I think the retaggers here have been good at eliminating these from questions, particularly migrated questions (which need retagging anyway).

Essentially there should be five categories of questions on here:

1. Questions with `[stackoverflow]`, which are requests specifically related to Stack Overflow in some way;
2. Questions related to the Meta site itself (i.e., `[meta]`, `[meta-meta]`, etc.);
3. `[faq]` (self-explanatory)
4. Questions with neither `[stackoverflow]` nor `[stackexchange]` nor `[meta]` (etc.) which are for engine features/support/discussion/etc.
5. Questions related to supplementary sites of Stack Exchange 2.0 (i.e., `[area51]`, `[reputation-leagues]`, etc.)

Anything else is off-topic.

---

That means there is additional work to do to remove `[stackexchange]` and/or `[stackexchange-2.0]` from a lot of questions (looks like about 350 of them).

Any `[stackexchange]` questions that refer only to SE1.0 sites should be closed as off-topic and deleted, as they should be on meta.stackexchange (I haven't checked, but I think this is probably quite clean already -- Jeff is aggressive with closing this stuff, and rightfully so -- there may be some stragglers that need deleting). An exception to that would be discussions about interactions of SE1.0 sites with SOFU sites, such as questions about MathOverflow as it relates to SO -- that sort of thing.

I think the final result we should see is a complete elimination of `[stackexchange]` and `[stackexchange-2.0]`, and an introduction of a new tag `[stackexchange-1.0]` for the discussions involving the legacy sites (as mentioned in the previous paragraph). Doing that segregation is a good first step, as we can probably get Jeff to database-dump the other tags once the required human intervention is complete.

Certainly there's a lot to go through... I'm always wary of flooding Meta's homepage because people come here for urgent help and bumping questions off the front page isn't really considerate to those people. So, yeah, we an all chip in a few at a time. Eventually they'll all get done.

Comment: I'm confused. You say SE 1.0 questions should be closed and deleted, but you also say there should be a `[stackexchange-1.0]` tag. Are you proposing the `[stackexchange-1.0]` tag purely as a way to identify posts that should be mass-deleted? Also, what tag __would__ you suggest for network-wide issues (e.g. "how do I report abusive users"), or questions about the SE engine (e.g. "how does comment voting work")?

Comment: @Popular "An exception to that would be discussions about interactions of SE1.0 sites with SOFU sites, such as questions about MathOverflow as it relates to SO -- that sort of thing." As for network-wide issues, that doesn't require a tag and is implicit to being on this site. It'd be like tagging questions on Food & Cooking with "cooking" - it'll implicitly understood that a question is going to be about the general engine and network in the absence of any specific qualifiers like [stackoverflow] or [area51].

Comment: @Grace, um... I swear that exception wasn't there at 2 am. I'm not really on board with the no tag for network-wide issues; it feels weird to have a special tag for one of this site's purposes (being SO's per-site meta) but not the other (being the network/engine's meta).

Comment: @Popular Think of it this way - how many of the per-meta-sites actually have a tag to indicate questions about their parent sites? I see Meta as operating primarily as the whole network's meta. SO is more of a subset of that network, which makes it useful to identify when a question is specifically about SO rather than the whole engine/network. Honestly, it's why I've found the [site-agnostic] and [so-family] tags worthless since even before the per-site-meta system was established, as any question that isn't explicitly tagged with a site is implicitly about the whole network.

Comment: @Grace, where you see redundant information, I see potentially missing information. Was the question supposed to be tagged `[stackoverflow]` and the OP forgot? Does the question belong on a per-site meta, and the OP got confused about where to ask? Granted, much of this information will be available from context, but there must be some ambiguous cases. And, um, I like making things organized and perfect.

Comment: @Popular We get a fair number of questions every day which are only tagged one or more of the required tags. Adding [stackoverflow] where it has been forgotten is part of the normal routine for us. Even before the per-site-meta system, we had to deal with questions about the whole network that were tagged [stackoverflow], and we dealt with it by removing the tag. But moreover, there is no difference in the potential in error by having another tag - people can forget to place the extra tag or add it inappropriately just the same as they can forget to leave nothing there.