# Why is Stack Overflow's meta also the meta of the whole Stack Exchange engine?

Tags: discussion, meta

I've just asked six questions on [Board and Card Games Meta](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/faq), and one has been referred to this site.  Looking closer, I realized that this meta site is not just for Stack Overflow, as it seems from its name.  I think I'll need to transfer a couple of my questions over here.

Why are the two metas (the one for Stack Overflow and the one for all sites) merged into one instead of being separate?

Comment: See [the per-site meta blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/), [Why is this meta different from the others?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58993/w) (and its duplicates), "Sometimes there are political and time reasons." – Jeff Atwood♦ ([source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57265/w/57377#57377)), [this now-sorta-outdated answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66495/u/66497#66497) and my own comment under [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69019/s).

Comment: Actually, [Stop special-casing Stack Overflow's meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73816/stop-special-casing-stack-overflows-meta) might be the best link for you. It's not _technically_ a duplicate, but its answers answer this question pretty comprehensively.

Comment: Update: [the separation is now just a few months away](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In the beginning there was One and the One was Stack Overflow.  And the one was good.  Very good.

Then there came Two - Server Fault - and it, also, was good.

Then there came a Third and the Third was Super User and it, like its brethren, was good.

And the Trilogy was born.

But they used Uservoice, which was only marginally good.  And, indeed it was noted as such and thus was born Meta Stack Overflow, and it was good.  And it came to pass that all sites in the trilogy were served by Meta Stack Overflow.

And the entities of the Trilogy grew, and grew.  And the One grew larger and faster.  And questions in Meta Stack Overflow became primarily about the One, with a smattering of the other two.

Then arose from the Creators' minds Area 51, which breathed life into the many sites which collectively became known as The Stack Exchange Network.  And it was decreed that each community having its own Meta site would be good.

However, since Meta Stack Overflow was firmly founded and well established and had vast knowledge of the inner workings of the Stack Exchange sites it was maintained as the Oracle of Stack Exchange as a whole, as is maintained to this day.

[or something like that]

Comment: +1 for dramatic flair

Comment: Meta was forced to eat Sir Atwood's minstrels. And there was much rejoicing.

Comment: Mmmm, minstrels! (They're a kind of chocolate round these parts…)

Comment: Taste like chicken

Comment: Not to nitpick, but MSO launched before SU :)

Comment: @Kyle yeah, yeah :)  I thought about that then had to go to a meeting.  Thought I'd just leave it as is instead of bumping it.  I actually didn't expect that this question would stay around long.