# Why is it meta.StackOverflow instead of meta.StackEchange?

Tags: discussion, meta, per-site-meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Stack Overflow's meta also the meta of the whole Stack Exchange engine?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96313/why-is-stack-overflows-meta-also-the-meta-of-the-whole-stack-exchange-engine)
>   [The future of meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange)

Why do we not have the cross-site meta at https://meta.stackexchange.com/ instead of here?

This means that the per-site meta for StackOverflow is mixed up with the cross-site meta.  When I was new here, I personally was confused about this meta and what is was for.

I suppose it is a bit late now as if it was to be changed, it would just cause even more confusion.

My question is why was it not like that in the first place?

Comment: see: [The future of meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124015/165773) "I think it's time that we gave Stack Overflow its own, true per-site meta, and moved the higher level network meta discussions to meta.stackexchange.com..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some background: in the beginning there were only three sites: Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User (aka the trilogy sites) where Stack Overflow was naturally the main site of the three so its Meta site got the most attention.

The "combined" https://stackexchange.com/ site still did not exist (as far as I know, would be glad to stand corrected) and it took years for the network to expand and for new sites to appear, while this Meta used to detect bugs, suggest new features and discuss stuff related to the whole network during the whole time.

When https://stackexchange.com/ did appear, its main goal as far as I can see was to act as a portal to all the sites. As Jeff said [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124015/165773), it did have its own Meta but not for the same purpose as other meta sites.

Anyhow looks like https://meta.stackexchange.com/ will be resurrected soon and this historical inconsistency will be remedied. :)

Comment: In your last paragraph you say 'soon', is there a source for that? Sure it isn't 6 to 8 weeks? :)

Comment: Well, Jeff said "It may be months away" back in the end of February - "months" might also be 8 so it's really close. ;-)