# StackExchange Meta Hierarchy

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Stack Overflow’s meta also the meta of the whole Stack Exchange engine?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96313/why-is-stack-overflows-meta-also-the-meta-of-the-whole-stack-exchange-engine)

I often post Feature requests, Bug reports, etc in meta.stackoverflow.com, but have been aware for a while that there is also metas for the sub sites. Thing is, they often (as far as I, wish them to / am aware they do without checking) apply to all sub sites.

When I try to navigate to [meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com), it brings me to [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), so I presume that this is supposed to be the site to post such global things to.

1. Is this correct?
2. Does anyone else think that there should be a meta.stackexchange.com that people can post these things to, to address issues, suggestions, etc for every site; or go to the seperate sub-sites meta to suggest something that they think would only work / be best for, that sub site (Also allowing posts to get migrated should someone, with the power to do so / enough votes, think that it should apply to all sub sites)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Stack Overflow's meta also the meta of the whole Stack Exchange engine?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96313/why-is-stack-overflows-meta-also-the-meta-of-the-whole-stack-exchange-engine) and [The future of meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange)