# Can we change the faq for meta stackoverflow to include how meta SO is the exception to the rule of how meta sites work?

Tags: support, meta

So I'm new here. Please don't flame me. I've [searched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64399/should-we-edit-retag-questions-written-about-so-that-are-really-about-se/64423#64423) and [asked questions](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/whats-the-difference-between-discussion-user-and-main-user) trying to understand all the differences between meta stackoverflow and any other meta site but I think it should be stated more clearly in the faq.

As I understand the way to clear the confusion would be to have meta site for the SE engine separate from meta SO (and even maybe a meta for Area51). However that is not possible due to extensive technical and cultural reasons.

So that leaves us with meta SO for questions about SE, SO, and Area51. From my understanding this makes meta SO behave differently from other meta sites (such as rep not carrying over from child SO site). The question I linked to above has a lot of information about SE 1.0 and 2.0 and how to handle tags. I believe some of this information should be in the faq or about instead in a question. So my main questions are.

**What are all the differences between meta SO and other meta sites?**

**Can we update the faq (in meta SO and Area51) to explicitly explain that meta SO is different from other meta sites?**

**Can we update the 'asking help' site / 'How to ask' box next to question form to include Area51 and how to tag questions relating to each?**

I know many of you already know all of this but as a new user I hope I can use my 'new user' perspective to point out areas confusing for new users.

Comment: I found the community faq for SE 2.0 sites but what about SE 1.0 sites? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: et al - Are any SE 1.0 sites still alive?

Comment: @Dori Math Overflow, and maybe a few others.

Comment: @Dori, I thought SE 1.0 and SOFU and the original trilogy sites were all the same thing.